# Can we say that no matter what philosophy a person holds, it must break down sometimes, because human must hold double standards?

Tags: ethics

Can we say that no matter what philosophy a person holds, ultimately, all humans use double standards to live?  The reason is: all continuously living human beings, will prefer to eat other living things, and not want to be eaten by other living things.  Because if there is any human that is not using this way of thinking, and not eat other living things (plants, or animals), he or she will not live past a few days or weeks.

Or can we say that no matter what philosophy a person holds, it needs to break down sometimes, because, ultimately, all humans use double standards in order to live?  Unless, if the philosophy itself already include this double standard element in it.

Comment: why do you lump plants and animals together?

Comment: What is wrong with eating things?  Or, alternatively, do you mean by "double standard" "making no distinctions"?  I agree that it is very difficult to exist without drawing distinctions.  The world is not uniform.

Comment: @Rex I think you are asking "What is wrong with eating things" just because you are so used to the idea.  Do you know that Chicken or Sheep has children and the mother chicken likes to protect the children, and the children love to be around the mother?  So what is wrong about eating the mother, you ask.  To turn the question around, what if there are space aliens and they say, "What's wrong about eating humans", and you may be able to give 20 reasons in 5 minutes.

Comment: @動靜能量 - As a practical matter, most chickens raised for food in industrialized countries do not have chicks these days.  I'm not sure this is better for the chickens involved, but that's how it goes.  Anyway, it's entirely possible to live as a vegetarian, and lettuce does not have children who like to be around mother lettuce, and it is also possible to draw distinctions between chickens and humans.  As I said before: the world is not uniform.  We do make distinctions.  Your reasoning only can work if we do not--otherwise, maybe there is a distinction between a human and the thing being eaten

Answer (score 3):

> The reason is: all continuously living human beings, will prefer to eat other living things, and not want to be eaten by other living things.

Alternative wordings of your question might include, "Is it practical to live without hypocrisy?", or, "Is it possible to apply the [golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule) to all acts consistently?"

If I understand you as you mean, then you would define *"holding a double standard"* as

> desiring to act upon a *self-like* class of entities while desiring *not* to be *samely acted upon* by that class of entities.

For example,

```
class LivingThing
{
    public void Eat(LivingThing& anotherLivingThing);
};
```

Instantiations of this class would be *holding a double standard* if they desired to invoke `LivingThing::Eat` while desiring *not* to become the parameter themselves.

I use this example not (only) because you have 17,874 reputation on Stack Overflow :p, but because, for me at least, it isolates the major ambiguity: **What constitutes a `LivingThing`?**

- Would you consider microorganisms in the air `LivingThing`s?  Or only multicellular organisms?  Or perhaps, only multicellular organisms with sentience, *i.e.* not plants?
- To be "eligible for double-standardness," do two entities need to *be* `LivingThing`s, as in, be instantiations of the base or a derived class, *i.e.* must they be linked by a nature of *what they are*?  Or, do two entities simply need to *do* things that `LivingThing`s do, as in, implement a common interface (er, abstract class), *e.g.* is it a double standard for us *to desire to destroy* a computer, if we also desire *not to be destroyed* by a computer?  (In this context, personally, I believe the object-oriented and functional views are the same.)

I understand that "living things" was only one example.  But generally speaking, and maybe this is what Rex Kerr was getting at too, I believe that no matter what you talk about, the same ambiguities would arise, because lumping and distinction are operations local and subjective to our brains.

Comment: It's a good point, but both I and tea cups are unambiguously objects.  I want to lift my tea cup, and not have my tea cup lift me.  Ambiguity is not the problem; absurdity is.

Comment: @RexKerr: I would have no qualms about being lifted by my tea cup, if I was confident that no ill would come to me by it and that it didn't pose an obstacle for my personal objectives. Being eaten, however, is commonly accepted as presenting a major obstacle to achieving one's goals.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap - Well--I don't want my tea cup to pour liquids out of me and into it, either.  I don't want my light bulb to pass electrical current through me and heat me to 2000C.  I don't want the oxygen in the air to tear me in half and bind each half to carbon.

Comment: @RexKerr: sure. Those things are likely to be uncomfortable, or otherwise get in the way of other things you would like to do.

Comment: @Rex but would you like the Ferris Wheel to pick you up if you paid $5 to ride the Ferris Wheel?  Would you like the roller coaster to move you if you lined up for 30 minutes for it?  I think your answer will be a natural yes.  So it really depends on a person's desire or "what benefits" he or she can gain.  If benefit, yeah, it makes sense and is correct.  If loss, harm or no benefit, then not correct.  And "absurdity".  It is merely using personal benefit vs loss to "feel" or "think" about things.

Comment: @動靜能量 - I think you're still missing the point.  If "I want to eat shrimp" but "I don't want shrimp to eat me" is a double standard and logically problematic, "I want to make my light bulb filament be 2000C" but "I don't want my light bulb filament to make me be 2000C" is also a double standard and logically problematic.

Comment: @Rex it is meant for looking at the phenomenon of people wanting to be a director, or VP, or CEO, to command other people and not want to be commanded; or people who want to be first class citizen and be higher and not want to be treated as second class citizen. And I used to "want to eat" and "not want to be eaten" to illustrate that.  But if you start to say, "want the light bulb to be 2000C and not want the light bulb to change us to 2000C", then you are merely making it sound absurd to "disprove" the idea

Comment: @動靜能量 - I am pointing out that you have not drawn any distinction in your question between absurd statements and less-absurd ones.  I am using this in analogy to proof by contradiction to show that your premises are flawed.  Fix the premises--so that the absurdities are ruled out--and then let's see if we still have a problem with eating.

Comment: @Rex you are missing the point.  I am not talking about eating.  I am talking about people holding double standard, less obvious if we say "want to command and not want to be commanded", etc, and is more obvious in every day "want to eat" and "not want to be eaten", that whatever a philosophy is, it has to break down, day by day, unless it already has a double standard element in it.  if you say the world isn't uniform, maybe that's a valid point.  Then philosophy may have to have a self-biased point.

Comment: @RexKerr - With all due respect, I feel 動靜能量's inquiry was clear enough for us to infer certain obvious premises. 動靜能量 brings to light examples (the desire to eat, the desire to command) that show that we, as human beings, hold "non-reflexive desires" (if "double standard" is an undesirably loaded term). By "proof by contradiction" you seem to assert that this discussion cannot advance until certain premises are fixed, but I disagree: it seems you are stubbornly refusing to fill in obvious premises that would lead to a more relevant discussion of 動靜能量's question.

Comment: @RexKerr (cont'd) - If however the general consensus is that 動靜能量's question was indeed ill-defined (in which case I'd owe you an apology for these well-meaning but blunt comments), then I'd continue to assert that this discussion isn't dead: we just need to limit the domain of entities to _human beings_; for 動靜能量 seems to have generalized his question without needing to do so. The new question would be something like: **Is it possible to live consistently (without hypocrisy) in any system of ethics?**

Comment: @RexKerr (cont'd) - From there, generalizing these principles to non-human entities are a matter of definition, and what I was originally trying to untangle. What entities are "similar enough" to be considered "self-like" and deserving of our attention and empathy?  (Personally, I would draw the line at sentient beings. I would not consider tea cups nor light bulbs entities to which the principles are applicable. Subjective of course, but that was partially my point from the beginning.)

Comment: @acheong87 - I disagree: one of the most interesting lines of inquiry regarding hypocrisy is in fact exactly which premises you're holding; 動靜能量 presents an example of eating which you expand upon, but neither of you really explain what the scope of the inquiry is, and how you chose premises.  Allow too much and you get absurdity.  Allow too little and there is no issue: ("If I am the current democratically elected President of the United States, I do not want to be ruled by other current Presidents of the United States").  Thus, premises and scope are the _first_ thing we should examine.

Comment: @RexKerr - Months too late, but I think I now see what you mean, and I appreciate your persistence, and especially that you were not dismissive of my naivete. I think if you had said, "I see where _you're_ going with this, but _I'm_ insisting that a rigorous consideration of the premises may do away with these 'problems' altogether; why don't you give the thought a try?" then I would have felt more willing. But without your expressing that there _was_ indeed _something_ interesting in this discussion, unfortunately it felt to me, at that time, like you were just trying to end the conversation.

Comment: @RexKerr - So, I agree. I think a deeper examination of the premises would have led to more relevant insights about the "problem" we were perceiving.

Comment: @acheong87 - Sorry I didn't convey myself clearly.  It can be a challenge to identify which part of a problem someone else is perceiving differently.  I'm glad you eventually understood what I was trying to express!

Answer (score 1):

Your example of eating and being eaten does not produce an unsolvable moral problem, for it is easy to defend the position that killing living things in order for human beings to survive is right, as is always has been done (although there certainly are valid opposite positions, e.g. Singer's preference utilitarianism).

Of course you could make the empirical observation that persons live by a double standard, but neither can you claim that this is true for all persons in history, past and prospective (problem of induction), nor can you conclusively claim that it is an ontological/anthropological condition for being human, because there is no logical need in being hypocritical. One might be "forced" by life to abandon one's maxims, but in that moment one has to simply accept that one's leaving the "moral path" to instead act by hypothetical imperatives (cleverness) or arbitrariness. One does, however, have the choice to not do that. As long as one has this option, there can be no "need" for double standards (and there is no moral act without options).

The answer to your question, "can we say that...", probably depends on who "we" are. I'd say that it is not a valid philosophical conclusion. However an empirical science could phrase that theory, and then it's up to the empirical evidence to "proof" (we know there is no proof...) whether or not the theory is conclusive.

Comment: While I do agree that one can defend the position of killing living things, I want to point out that you have chosen an appeal to tradition as an example.